# Build an array using inject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration, enumeration, inject

I'm trying to build an array using inject. I expect `consents` to be an array of `ParticipantConsent` objects.

Each `ParticipantConsent` object can `:have_many` `ParticipantConsentSample` objects.

I expect `sc` to contain an array of arrays of `ParticipantConsentSample` objects associated with every `ParticipantConsent` object associated with a `Participant`.

```
consents = ParticipantConsent.where(:participant_id => @participant.id).all
sample_consents = consents.inject { |sc, c| sc << ParticipantConsentSample.where(:participant_consent_id => c.id).all }
```

Currently getting back the contents of `consents` when I check the contents of `sample_consents`. Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `sample_consents` to be an array, you need to initialize it as one using an argument to `inject`:

```
sample_consents = consents.inject([]) { |sc, c| ... }
```

Comment: This is a terrible example because it ignores the trap that new Ruby programmers can get caught in: the injected value **must** be the last line of the injection block.

Answer (score 3):

try the below:

```
sample_consents = consents.inject([]) do |sc, c| 
  sc << ParticipantConsentSample.where(participant_consent_id: c.id).to_a
  sc
end
```

Comment: I cleaned up your code but you don't need an inject for a simple array. Just use a map.

Comment: No need for standalone `sc` line in the block, as it is [returned from the previous line](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C). Don't you love Ruby :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you just want an array of arrays obtained from ParticipantConsentSample, you don't really want `inject`, you want `map`:

```
sample_consents = consents.map do |c|
  ParticipantConsentSample.where(:participant_consent_id => c.id).all
end
```